# Can't running my program in Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, python-3.6

I downloaded Python 3.6.5 and while I trying to run my program, opened a black window and closed (like a cmd window).
What I need to do?

Comment: This sounds like expected behavior.  Either run it in an interactive console, or add something like `input()` at the end so it waits for an "Enter" before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Install any client where you can execute the commands. And execute the command **python file.py**.